# iphone- Push a view after poping earlier view

Tags: iphone

I have one view pushed on navigation.
Now I do following on click of button.

```
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    FreeStuffViewController * freeStuffVC=[[FreeStuffViewController   alloc]initWithNibName:@"FreeStuffViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:freeStuffVC animated:YES];
    [freeStuffVC release];
```

It only pops a view, but dint push new FreeStuffVc.
Please help.

Comment: It is because after popping, the view control directly transfers to the previous view  skipping the remaining code.

Comment: is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
FreeStuffViewController * freeStuffVC=[[FreeStuffViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FreeStuffViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:freeStuffVC animated:YES];
NSMutableArray *viewArray = [[self.navigationController viewControllers] mutableCopy];
[viewArray removeObjectAtIndex:viewArray.count - 2];
self.navigationController.viewControllers = viewArray;
```

Comment: It gives following worning message  "Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted"

Answer (score 0):

this works fine. Check it

```
        UINavigationController *local = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];
        [local popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
        newView *nr=[[newView alloc]init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:nr animated:YES];
```